# Special characters setup PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Everytime I make a new project, I end up in having troubles because I forgot to create the database collation by UTF-8 or there are some characters that slipped trough that I didn't see like é/à/.. but also the double .. or tripple ... seem to be very nasty. I usually use **mysqli_real_escape_string** to make sure he writes the characters away, and when i print them i use **htlmentities**. But that doesn't work for all characters, and defenitly not for double .. or tripple ... .

Is there a general rule / guideline that I should keep in mind when setting up a project, so I don't have troubles with these special characters?

Comment: Guideline: Use UTF-8 all the way thru!?!

Comment: For those having problems behind me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through was a good guideline!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a general rule / guideline that I should keep in mind when setting up a project?

Sure.
**Always set your database connection charset to match your HTML page actual charset.**

Say, your pages are in utf-8, then issue

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
```

right after connect

of your pages are in Windows-1251, then make it

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'cp1252');
```

and so on

Also always use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to format **string literals** you're adding into query dynamically,
and use `htmlspecialchars()` when printing **user input** back to HTML page

**Update:**
Also you need to setup your tables with charset that supports all the required characters (UTF-8 is a preferred default).

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    ...
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

when creating your tables with such definition you will never have ?s in your data

Comment: That works for the double and tripple . , but if I now write data to my database, it is inserting every special character as an ?.

Comment: Ok, this is what I did: I've set up my DB charset to UTF8, changed my al my db default charsets en DB charset. And now he just writes empty data (in what I believe are characters utf can't handle (Ø20)) and in the other tables he keeps writing ? in characters like é / è or à. Am I missing something?